# How can i filter mysql data if a column has multiple comma separated values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to ask how can i filter mysql data if the condition is checked for a column with several comma separated values. I give you an example -

I have following table say "tbitems" -

```
id     item_names     item_types    item_features
1      item 1        8,6          10,5,4,9,8,6
2      item 2        8,6          10,5,8
```

Now suppose i want to fetch the records (items) that have item types either 8 or 6 but having item_features exactly equal to what we specify for example 10, 5, and 4.

I know for the first condition (item types) we can use IN operator.

But I don't know how we can filter the record based on item_features.

I can write the query like this -

`SELECT * FROM`tbitems`WHERE`item_types`IN (8) AND`item_features` **WHAT OPERATOR SHOULD COM HERE TO SELECT ONLY THESE VALUES** ( 4, 5, 10)

If i use IN like i did for first condition then the second row of above table is also fetched because 5 and 10 are available in the set (10,5,8) but i want to extract only first row. Any idea?

**EDIT -**

Sorry, your workaround didn't work.

I wanted to get only first row of this table -

[image]

But now it is yielding some extra rows that i didn't want. And moreover i cant use so many FIND_IN_SET since there comma-separated values may be large in numbers. Also i couldn't use this sql in my PHP code.

Answer (score 4):

For you current scenario you can do so by using `FIND_IN_SET` each time you need to match the `item_features`

```
SELECT * FROM
table1
WHERE
item_types
IN (8) AND FIND_IN_SET(4,item_features)
AND FIND_IN_SET(5,item_features)
AND FIND_IN_SET(10,item_features)
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d778b/3)

> But i ask youif its possible to change the schema then first normalize
>   your structure see [**Database normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization),store all the relations in a separate table ,like a junction table for `item_types_relations` which store the current table id and all the items id in a junction table as one-to-many and a same junction table for `item_features_relation`

**EDIT** As per @Ravinder's comment

```
SELECT * FROM
table1
WHERE
FIND_IN_SET(8,item_types)
AND FIND_IN_SET(4,item_features)
AND FIND_IN_SET(5,item_features)
AND FIND_IN_SET(10,item_features)
```

Comment: If `item_types` stores data in csv format, `in` will not work. Check with `item_types in (6)`. It results a `false`.

Comment: @Ravinder update my post thanks for the reason why it won't work

Comment: Yes you are right - the database should be normalized but sorry to say i did not create it myself. I have to work what i have from others.

Answer (score 1):

If values are stored in CSV format, you have to use [***`FIND_IN_SET`***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). Use of `IN` will not work.

```
mysql> select * from ( select '8,6' i ) r where i in (8);
+-----+
| i   |
+-----+
| 8,6 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from ( select '8,6' i ) r where i in (6);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

**Try this**:

```
SELECT * FROM tbitems
WHERE  find_in_set( 8, item_types ) 
  AND  find_in_set( 4, item_features )
  AND  find_in_set( 5, item_features )
  AND  find_in_set( 10, item_features )
```