# php mysql select data where column array

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have in the database articles table :

```
id- cat  -  title 

1-  10,2 -  the title

2-  5,10 -  the title

3-  7    -  the title

4-  7,4,3 - the title
```

I want to select the articles where `cat = '10'` which means `article id 1 and 2`.

I have used `MySQL LIKE` but it does not work well.

Any idea ?

Comment: Your table structure looks wonky. Comma separated values in a column is a bad practice. You may want to break it into separate tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i filter mysql data if a column has multiple comma separated values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006392/how-can-i-filter-mysql-data-if-a-column-has-multiple-comma-separated-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
select * from your_table
where find_in_set(10, cat) > 0
```

But actually the better solution would be to normalize your table and store only one value in a column!

You can do this by adding another table

```
article_categories table
------------------------
article_id
category_id
```